# Django ModelChoiceField in ModelForm passes None

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django.
I'm making form to add timetable to specific branch.
So I have 'Branch' model and 'Timetable' model.
'Branch' model is in 'branches' app and 'Timetable' model is in 'schedules' app.
What I'm expecting is when users fill in the form to add timetable, they can choose which branch to add it from select box.

Here is my codes
branches/models.py

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
phone_validator = RegexValidator(
    regex="\d{2,4}-?\d{3,4}(-?\d{4})?",
    message="It's not correct phone number format.",
)


class Branch(models.Model):
    srl = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="Serial")
    name = models.TextField(verbose_name="Branch name")
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name="Postcode")
    address1 = models.TextField(verbose_name="Road address")
    address2 = models.TextField(verbose_name="Detail address", blank=True)
    phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=13, validators=[phone_validator], verbose_name="Phone 1")
    phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=13, validators=[phone_validator], verbose_name="Phone 2", blank=True)
    is_opened = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Is opened?")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Branch"
        verbose_name_plural = "Branches"
        ordering = ["srl"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("branches:detail", kwargs={"srl": self.srl})
```

schedules/models.py

```
import datetime

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class Timetable(models.Model):
    srl = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="Serial")
    branch_srl = models.ForeignKey(
        "branches.Branch",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Branch Serial",
    )
    period = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=2,
        decimal_places=0,
        verbose_name="Period",
    )
    period_length = models.DurationField(
        default=datetime.timedelta(minutes=50),
        verbose_name="Period Length",
    )
    is_holiday = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Is holiday?")
    start_time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(10, 00), verbose_name="Start time")
    end_time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(23, 00), verbose_name="End time")
```

schedules/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField, ModelForm

from branches.models import Branch
from schedules.models import Schedule, Timetable


class TimetableForm(ModelForm):
    branch_choices = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Branch.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        label="Branch",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-select"}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Timetable
        fields = (
            "branch_choices",
            "period",
            "period_length",
            "is_holiday",
            "start_time",
            "end_time",
        )
        labels = {
            "period": "Period",
            "period_length": "Period Length",
            "is_holiday": "Is Holiday?",
            "start_time": "Start Time",
            "end_time": "End Time",
        }
        widgets = {
            "period": forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "period_length": forms.TimeInput(
                format="%H:%M:%S",
                attrs={
                    "class": "form-control",
                },
            ),
            "is_holiday": forms.RadioSelect(
                choices=[(True, "Yes"), (False, "No")],
                attrs={
                    "class": "form-check-input",
                },
            ),
            "start_time": forms.TimeInput(
                attrs={
                    "type": "time",
                    "class": "form-control",
                },
            ),
            "end_time": forms.TimeInput(
                attrs={
                    "type": "time",
                    "class": "form-control",
                },
            ),
        }
```

Error message is this.
[Error message from Django debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v8Rr.png)

--- Edit 0 ---
I forgot to attach schedules/views.py
schedules/views.py

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from schedules.forms import TimetableForm
from schedules.models import Schedule, Timetable


# Create your views here.
class AddTimetableView(CreateView):
    model = Timetable
    form_class = TimetableForm
    # This should be changed. This is temporary
    success_url = reverse_lazy("schedules:index")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["page_title"] = "Add timetable"

        return context
```

--- Edit 1 ---
Here is my template
schedules/templates/scheduels/timetable_form.html
For your information, I'm using Bootstrap 5 and related CDN link is in main/base.html

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="POST" id="timetable-form" class="container d-grid gap-3 justify-content-evenly align-items-center">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label text-nowrap" for="{{ form.branch_choices.id_for_label }}">{{ form.branch_choices.label }}</label>
            <div class="col">{{ form.branch_choices }}</div>
            {{ form.branch_choices.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label text-nowrap" for="{{ form.period.id_for_label }}">{{ form.period.label }}</label>
            <div class="col">{{ form.period }}</div>
            {{ form.period.errors }}
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label text-nowrap" for="{{ form.period_length.id_for_label }}">{{ form.period_length.label }}</label>
            <div class="col">{{ form.period_length }}</div>
            {{ form.period_length.errors }}
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label text-nowrap" for="{{ form.is_holiday.id_for_label }}">{{ form.is_holiday.label }}</label>
            <div class="col">
                {% for choice in form.is_holiday %}
                    <div class="form-check">
                        {{ choice.tag }}
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ choice.id_for_label }}">{{ choice.choice_label }}</label>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {{ form.is_holiday.errors }}
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label text-nowrap" for="{{ form.start_time.id_for_label }}">{{ form.start_time.label }}</label>
            <div class="col">{{ form.start_time }}</div>
            {{ form.start_time.errors }}
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label text-nowrap" for="{{ form.end_time.id_for_label }}">{{ form.end_time.label }}</label>
            <div class="col">{{ form.end_time }}</div>
            {{ form.end_time.errors }}
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">저장</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I got an answer from [Django Forum](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/modelchoicefield-in-modelform-passes-none/15308/2). One of the causes is I though if I use same name with model might cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way of setting queryset-related choices on a model form is like by overriding the `__init__()` method of the form, rather than manually creating a form field.

```py
class TimetableForm(ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.branches = Branch.objects.all()
        super(TimetableForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['branch_srl'].queryset = self.branches
```

Furthermore, because you are using a `ModelForm` a lot of the labels and field definition should be automatic based on what you have defined on the model. Try to avoid repeating those declarations if you can avoid it.

Comment: Can you tell me why my code doesn't work?

Comment: Hard to say - fundamentally, the data passed into the form is None and it violates the not-null constraint of the model. So it might be an issue with your template (how the form is rendered) or your view (how the form is processed).

Comment: My guess is it might be not a template problem. Because I use same template to 'Branch' model and add branch info. Difference is, there is no foreign key and ModelChoiceField in 'branches' app. I think it could be a view problem. The view handles 'add timetable' is subclass of CreateView and I didn't change anything in it. I even didn't override form_valid or other methods.

Comment: By the way, thank you for additional information related to label. I thought I should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [CodenameTim](https://forum.djangoproject.com/u/CodenameTim) from [Django Forum](https://forum.djangoproject.com/), I found the [solution](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/modelchoicefield-in-modelform-passes-none/15308/2)
So I copied the solution below for who experiencing the same issue.

> The error is saying that the field branch_srl is null when it’s being inserted so it violates the `NOT NULL CONSTRAINT`. If you check your form, the form doesn’t use that field, but instead it uses `branch_choices`. You need to map the selected value for that field to `branch_srl` somewhere. It can be in `TimetableForm.save()`, `AddTimetableView.form_valid()` or you could rename the field `branch_choices` to `branch_srl` so it saves through to the database.